# PowerShell send-mailmessage

Tags: powershell, mailmessage

How do I terminate cmdlet prompts for To[] address?
It keeps asking for more!
this is what I see:

```
send-mailmessage
cmdlet Send-MailMessage at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
From: ABCD@boo.edu
Subject: test
To[0]: DCBA@foo.com
To[1]: jhgjjg@trtre.com
To[2]:???????
```

Comment: don't type anything and press enter

Comment: nope. it generates an error: 
Send-MailMessage : Mail cannot be sent because no SMTP server was specified
Looks like it attempts to execute immediately imstead of prompting for more parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to at least include the SMTP server argument in the command because you won't get a prompt for it:

```
Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer "yoursmtpserver"
```

Once you've done that, enter your 'to' addresses as normal, and when you're done, press enter once more to escape from the final prompt and send the email.

Better yet, just enter the entire command with parameters included:

```
Send-MailMessage -From "ABCD@boo.edu" -To @("DCBA@foo.com", "jhgjjg@trtre.com") -Subject "test" -Body "Testing PS Email" -SmtpServer "yoursmtpserver"
```

Comment: It doesn't prompt for message body or anything else. If I supply server as you suggest it sends empty message as soon as i hit enter after To[1]:    Is it normal?  does it ONLY prompts for From, Subject and To?

Comment: It only prompts for From, Subject, and To because those are the only 3 required parameters.  That's why I suggest including all the parameters in one command.

Comment: Ohh I see now. Thanks!